# NSCurl ATS works, IOS 9 does not

Tags: ios, security, nsurl

Here is the log from NSCURL:

```
Default ATS Secure Connection
---
ATS Default Connection
ATS Dictionary:
{
}
Result : PASS
---
```

And from IOS 9 simulator:

```
2015-11-02 20:52:29.928 energyvue[1137:17754] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

The url is on port 9445 though.  Is there anyway to make this work without overriding ats transport security?

Comment: Can you share the URL you are looking at? Are you using `nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose`?

Comment: I have the same problem. The nscurl --ats-diagnostics pass into all tests but my app can´t communicate with my api (SURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802). My app is an Ionic Hybrid App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, and communication works on Simulator iOS9.2 but not into device.

I fixed my problem checking CFNetwork log on device (http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.com.br/2015/07/using-cfnetworkdiagnostics-for-network.html) and using a Cordova ATS Hybrid App Demo as sample (http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).

My final ATS configuration:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
       <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

My environment:

- API using HTTPS TLSv1.2 with SNI (Amazon AWS Cloud front, S3 and Elasticbeanstalk)
- iPhone 5S iOS 9.2 and Mac OS X El Capitan
- Hibrid App with Ionic Framework and AngularJS